# Insert a value in a string and check right position

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to solve my problem:
I receive a string like "Hello world.\nHi" and a certain position where I have to add a char.
So the problem is that the position is for a string without \n and I need to find out a way to count those '\n' and define how many '\n's are there before position to increment it.

Here's an example:

```
$string="Hi\nThis is\na test";
$position=7;
$value=0;
//CODE
$correct_result="Hi\nThis 0is\na test";
$wrong_result="Hi\nThi0s is\na test";
```

So basically I just need a way to check how many '\n's are there before the position

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using substr from 0 to $position and using count to check if there where "\n"